# Postgres - Changing values within columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns a wide dataset with one row per student and multiple columns per 'score':

```
Student ID     score1     score2     score3...
12345            101        102        103
67890            102        103        104
```

The scores are not actual scores, but instead are score ids that need to be translated to actual scores.

I would like to return the actual scores instead of the score ids. I know that I can just write a bunch of CASE statements that will do the translation for each column, but there are about 20 columns that need to be translated. I'm hoping that there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Cheers,
Jonathon

Comment: Store the translations in another table, then join that table in.

Comment: I guess that you should to change the original query instead of trying to deal with its results.

Comment: Please post the table definitions underlying the query and the query itself if you want something more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to make a scores table and then join to that.  That will take away the need to write an absurd case query.

```
CREATE TABLE code_scores (
ScoreID INT 
, Value INT)
    GO 

INSERT INTO code_scores (scoreid, value)
VALUES 
(101, 100)
, (102, 99)
GO 

SELECT studentID, score1, value
FROM yourtable 
INNER JOIN code_scores
 on score1 = scoreID
```

Comment: `sql` is not mean `ms sql server` BTW.